# Mac address reverts to the original address?

Tags: mac-spoofing

I was trying to change my mac address using the following command

`ifconfig wlan0 down`

`macchanger -r wlan0`

`ifconfig wlan0 up`

the mac address does change after this but when I try to ping any website I am unable to. Also after I manually reconnect with the wifi the mac address reverts back to normal. I tried googling it and read an article where the guy was turning off the `network-manager` off and back on again. I tried doing both of them and it still keeps reverting back to normal. I am using Parrot OS.

**EDIT: after switching wireless card to "UP", it shows that I am connected to the network and yet I am unable to ping, after reconnecting the connection is restored and so if the mac address**

Answer (score 0):

You might look at what address your macchanger is giving you. Times are changing and it looks like if your MAC address starts with a leading 1 bit, then it is a local address, and some drivers wont work with it. Take a look here on wikipedia about local addresses [Local Addresses on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details).

> Addresses can either be universally administered addresses or locally
>   administered addresses. A universally administered address is uniquely
>   assigned to a device by its manufacturer.
>
> Universally administered and locally administered addresses are
>   distinguished by setting the second-least-significant bit of the first
>   octet of the address. This bit is also referred to as the U/L bit,
>   short for Universal/Local, which identifies how the address is
>   administered. If the bit is 0, the address is universally
>   administered. If it is 1, the address is locally administered. In the
>   example address 06-00-00-00-00-00 the first octet is 06 (hex), the
>   binary form of which is 00000110, where the second-least-significant
>   bit is 1. Therefore, it is a locally administered address.
>   Consequently, this bit is 0 in all OUIs.

Take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/243818/change-mac-address-of-a-wireless-network-adapter . This has been discussed on other stackoverflow sites.